# My earliest/earlier works

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, superlatives

> These paintings are my **earliest** works

or

> These paintings are my **earlier** works

Which one of this sentence is correct if I want to say that the paintings are the ones I paint at the beginning of my carrier?

I've done some [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my%20earlier%20works%2C%20my%20earliest%20works&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmy%20earlier%20works%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20earliest%20works%3B%2Cc0) search, it said that 'earlier' is more commonly used, but I feel like 'earliest' sounds more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Earliest**" means *the most early*, hence would refer to the first of your paintings.
"**Earlier**" means *the early ones, without a specific timestamp*, so it would refer to any of your previous paintings.

Hence, **earliest** would describe those paintings perfectly, without any doubt of the time-of-their-making in the audience's mind.

Comment: I would add that "earlier" would probably not refer to a painting you completed a month ago if your painting career is longer than, say, 5 years. Using "earlier works" implies that there is a cut off and that you have a cohort of "later works" or "recent works" that do not solely include the painting you are working on